# Flink TumblingEventTimeWindows how achievement without overlap?

Tags: apache-flink

There is this text in [Stream Processing with Apache Flink](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/stream-processing-with/9781491974285/) page 211

> “The WindowAssigner determines for each arriving element to which windows it is assigned.”

then I study source code of [TumblingEventTimeWindows](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/assigners/TumblingEventTimeWindows.html)

```
public class TumblingEventTimeWindows extends WindowAssigner<Object, TimeWindow> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

...............................

    @Override
    public Collection<TimeWindow> assignWindows(
            Object element, long timestamp, WindowAssignerContext context) {
        if (timestamp > Long.MIN_VALUE) {
            if (staggerOffset == null) {
                staggerOffset =
                        windowStagger.getStaggerOffset(context.getCurrentProcessingTime(), size);
            }
            // Long.MIN_VALUE is currently assigned when no timestamp is present
            long start =
                    TimeWindow.getWindowStartWithOffset(
                            timestamp, (globalOffset + staggerOffset) % size, size);
            return Collections.singletonList(new TimeWindow(start, start + size));
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Record has Long.MIN_VALUE timestamp (= no timestamp marker). "
                            + "Is the time characteristic set to 'ProcessingTime', or did you forget to call "
                            + "'DataStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(...)'?");
        }
    }

...............................
```

from the source code I can found , It is true that elements are assigned to the window ,**new TimeWindow(start, start + size)** meanning each element be assigned a new TimeWindow.

but I am confused, TumblingEventTimeWindows how achievement without overlap?

if every element be  assigned a new TimeWindow,  the results are as follows

[image: overlap maybe on window]

There is no guarantee that each window will not overlap , Can someone point me in the direction of TumblingEventTimeWindows how achievement without overlap?

Comment: and the book also states : "The WindowAssigner returns zero, one, or multiple window
objects. The window operator groups elements based on the returned objects. Hence, a window object holds the information used to distinguish windows from each other"

how distinguish windows from each other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TimeWindow` object isn't very important. It is a simple structure that holds the start and end timestamps for the window, and nothing else. It's name makes it sound important, but it's just used to encode a copy of the information describing the time interval the incoming event is being assigned to.

It's actually the `WindowOperator` that has the important window data. Logically it's keeping something like a map, where the keys are the intervals described by the `TimeWindow` objects, and the values are the lists of events assigned to those intervals.

Comment: excuse me, The only codes I could find related to the map class in WindowOperator.java is

@Override
        public <UK, UV> MapState<UK, UV> getMapState(MapStateDescriptor<UK, UV> stateProperties) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "Per-window state is not allowed when using merging windows.");
        }

but I In-depth research MapStateDescriptor ,It does not appear to be the "map" you are referring to

Comment: I found a lot of "merge window" codes, MergingWindowSet.java has a addWindow(W newWindow, MergeFunction<W> mergeFunction) method , it's Adds a new Window to the set of in-flight windows ,  what's  in-flight windows

Comment: Tumbling windows aren't merging windows, so those code paths aren't relevant to this specific example.

Comment: I'm afraid the implementation of Flink's datastream windows is very complex, and uses some rather obscure features of the underlying runtime.

Comment: Logically it's roughly equivalent to a map, but technically the window operator is actually storing the time window object in the namespace of the InternalAppendingState windowState that stores the window contents.

Comment: Thank you very much for your pointers, I'll learn it later in the process of use